# SQLite query problem

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I'm trying to select all the recent discussions replied by the user. But the following query doesn't work. Returns 0 entries. I'm new to sql, I guess there are something wrong in my using of "IN". Please help trouble-shooting this:

```
    SELECT * FROM discussions 
    WHERE discussable_id IN 
    (SELECT commentable_id FROM comments 
    WHERE commentable_type = 'Discussion' AND user_id = 1);
```

also, what if I want to sort the above query by the comment.created_at? How do I do that? Plus, what if I want to also include all the discussions created by the user, and also sort all the query by the latest activity(could be discussion.created_at or comment.created_at). I'm in rails by the way. I've been trying to solving this for few hours. Would really appreciate any input. Thanks so much!

UPDATE2: Looks like I should replace discussable_id in the query with "id", did you spot it? :) such a tedious problem. Now, how do I order the returned discussions by comment.created_at? Should I open another question?

UPDATE1:
Sorry, here are the activerecord:

```
# Table name: discussions
#
#  id               :integer         not null, primary key
#  title            :string(255)     not null
#  content          :text(255)       not null
#  created_at       :datetime
#  updated_at       :datetime
#  user_id          :integer
#  discussable_id   :integer
#  discussable_type :string(255)
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
  #this is the scope that I'm having trouble with:
  scope :user_replied_group_discussions, lambda {|user| replied_by(user) }

  def last_reply
    if self.comments.any?
      self.comments.last.created_at
    else
      self.created_at
    end
  end
  private
    def self.replied_by(user)
      discussion_ids = %(SELECT commentable_id FROM comments 
                     WHERE commentable_type = 'Discussion' AND user_id = :user_id)
      where("discussable_type = 'Group' AND discussable_id IN (#{discussion_ids}) ", 
           { :user_id => user })
    end
end

# Table name: comments
#
#  id               :integer         not null, primary key
#  content          :text
#  created_at       :datetime
#  updated_at       :datetime
#  commentable_id   :integer
#  commentable_type :string(255)
#  user_id          :integer
#

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user

end
```

Anyway, I tried to run the sql query in the sqlite3 console, returns 0 entry. Thanks!

Comment: is dicussable_id and commentable_id are related? please post structure of discussions and comments table. and also mention how they are related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT d.* FROM discussions d
JOIN comments c
ON d.discussable_id = c.commentable_id
WHERE c.commentable_type = 'Discussion'
AND c.user_id = 1
```

That shows the same relationship as trying to be established by the `IN`. If that returns zero results, well, that's the answer ;-) Perhaps the relationships are not as expected? (It seems odd to have `d.discussable_id = c.commentable_id`.)

Happy coding.

Comment: You could try `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks! i've figured out why: see the UPDATE2, but now i want to order discussions by comment.created_at. should i open another question.

Comment: i've opened another question here, you are welcome to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695459/sql-query-order-problem